# Zeros of $\sinh z = z$ in $\mathbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

I must show that $f (z)= \sinh z - z$ has infinite zeros in $\mathbb C $, and that all zeros (except $0 $) are simple. Since the order of growth of $f $ is $1$, **if it had finitely many zeros we'd have $f (z)=p (z) e^{az+b}$.** Since if $z $ tends to $\infty $,  $f\sim e^z$, and if $z $ tends to $-\infty $, $f \sim e^{-z}$. This would mean that  $p(z) $ is constant, and that Re$  (a)$ is equal to both $1$ and $-1$, clearly absurd. However, I have no idea on how to prove that the nonzero zeros of $f $ are simple. Plus, I don't understand well why the proposition written in bold holds. Thanks for any clarify.

Comment: If any non-zero zero was not simple it would also be a zero of the derivative $\cosh z -1$. What can you conclude from this? The proposition comes from Weierstrass' theorem on the factorisation of entire functions.

Comment: @Gary I can conclude that the zeros would be contained in $W=\{\pi i + 2k \pi i \}$, with $k $ integer. However no number in $W $, except for $0$, is a zero of  $f $. (Since $\sin x  =0$ when cosine is $-1$ ). Is this right? For the proposition, I knew that it comes from Weierstrass theorem, however I still don't know how it follows from the general statement. Thanks